# I have added and commited on non existant branch; how do I get that commit onto a branch?

Tags: git

I added some untracked files and committed them, then I tried to push them and it said I wasn't on a branch. So I looked and I had branches

```
   * current
   Master
```

So I switched to branch master. The files are still there, but I don't remember all of their names. I can't switch back to the `*` branch.

How can I find that commit so I can push those untracked files? I have seen this happen before; I don't know how I keep doing it.

Answer (score 1):

Check `git reflog` it'll list all the commits your HEAD was on.

The lone commit will probably be there. To merge it onto master, you could just `git cherry-pick <commit SHA>`

Comment: What would happen if he `git merge <commit SHA>`? Same thing?

Comment: Yeah, but if there's commits in between, they'll be merged too. `cherry-pick` is safer if you only want a single commit, no matter the history (like if your commit wasn't based off master).